# how to deal with agora cloud recording error at stop

Tags: javascript

hello guys I am using agora cloud recording with amazon s3 but my I am getting an error when I stop the web page recording as below

```
fetch(`https://api.agora.io/v1/apps/${APP_ID}/cloud_recording/resourceid/${resource_id}/mode/web/start`,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            'Authorization':'Basic ' + authorization
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "cname": CHANNEL,
            "uid": UID.toString(),
            "clientRequest": {
                "token": token,
                "extensionServiceConfig": {
                    "errorHandlePolicy": "error_abort",
                    "extensionServices": [
                        {
                            "serviceName": "web_recorder_service",
                            "errorHandlePolicy": "error_abort",
                            "serviceParam": {
                                "url": window.location,
                                "audioProfile": 0,
                                "videoWidth": 1280,
                                "videoHeight": 720,
                                "maxRecordingHour": 1,
                                "maxVideoDuration": 200
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "recordingFileConfig": {
                    "avFileType": [
                        "hls",
                        "mp4"
                    ]
                },
                "storageConfig": {
                    "vendor": 1,
                    "region": 3,
                    "bucket": BUCKET_NAME,
                    "accessKey": ACCESS_KEY,
                    "secretKey": SECRET_KEY
                    "fileNamePrefix": [
                        "media",
                    ]
                }
            }
        })
        }).then(response => {
        return response.json().then(data => {
            sid = data.sid;
        })
        })
```

but I am a getting a response of 'Failed to find worker' from the server and I have properly entered my S3 bucket credentials.
Any help please